# Querying mint accounts which an account has mint authority over

Tags: query

is it possible to query all the mint accounts an account has mint authority over?

not token accounts owned by the address, just **mint accounts** - which the account might or might not hold minted tokens of

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although it's not super straightforward. You can use [`getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2) to get all signatures for a specific account. Then, you can use [`getTransactions`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTransactions) to fetch all transactions for an account.

At that point, you can filter for transactions that are calling the Token program and parse the mints from the transactions that use the [`setAuthority`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/interfaces/SetAuthorityInstructionData.html) and/or [`initializeMint`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/interfaces/InitializeMintInstructionData.html) instructions.

Finally, you'll need to fetch and parse the mints from the previous steps and filter out the ones that do not have your account as a mint authority (as that could've changed). The accounts you've got left over will be the mints over which your account has mint authority.